# Feature improvement for flags history

Tags: feature-request, flagging, profile-page

> **This question is asked on MSE at the following link for more visibility: [Make it easier to distinguish accepted and declined flags in addition to pending ones in flags history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/350210/feature-improvement-for-flags-history)**

In the flag summary section on a person's profile, it is difficult to differentiate the action of a flag. Although there is a feature to sort the flags' actions, it would be convenient to see them together. Just as the flags to be reviewed are highlighted with bold orange padding, it would be better to see a green background for the accepted flags and a red background for rejected flags.

[image: different flag types highlighted in flag summary]

In the given image just as the pending is in the given orange background, the helpful could have green background, and the self-removed could have a gray padding.

I edited the CSS and HTML files to show how it could look if implemented.

[image: "helpful" highlighted green in flag summary]

Comment: This is a solid idea, however it might go mostly unnoticed on this little meta and I don't think individual sites have that kind of control over that page. I encourage you to check out meta Stack Exchange and consider posting there so more people see it. It is up to you, MSE can be a bit rough compared to Ask Ubuntu and your post is certainly not off topic here. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @MarkKirby I did post it on MSE, here is a link. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/350210/feature-improvement-for-flags-history

Comment: I’m voting to close this question as a "cross-site duplicate" in order to focus on one version of the question. I added a link to the [meta.se] version of the question to the top of the post.

Comment: I don't think we should close (or, as a matter of past practice, have closed) questions on meta for that reason. A question on a child meta is an attempt to solicit input from a specific community. I've voted to reopen this.

Comment: @EliahKagan My reasoning was that edits to the post would need to be done in both places. Normally, a post like this one would better to have been flagged migration instead of being reposted on MSE if OP wants to post it on MSE.